# Forward traffic from IPSec clients to internet

Tags: iptables, ipsec

Here is what I want to do

CLIENT1 --- FIREWALL --- IPSec-TUNNEL --- SERVER --- Internet

I want CLIENT1 talk to internet through the IPSec Tunnel

IPSec tunnel is up between FIREWALL and SERVER and CLIENT1 traffic is routed through it.
When I ping from CLIENT1 to Internet IP, I can tcpdump icmp on the IPSec server but just that, nothing is forwarded

On SERVER

```
-A POSTROUTING -s CLIENT1-IP_ADDRESS -o eth0 -m policy --dir out --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source IPSEC-SERVER-IP-ADDRESS

-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 500 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 4500 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -m policy --dir in --pol ipsec --proto esp -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o eth0 -m policy --dir out --pol ipsec --proto esp -j ACCEPT
```

/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward is 1 for sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tell strongswan not to install_routes !!

vim /etc/strongswan.conf

```
charon {
        load_modular = yes
        install_routes = no
        plugins {
                include strongswan.d/charon/*.conf
        }
}

include strongswan.d/*.conf
```